# Java import geotools with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I woudlike to import geotools to my project but I have alwyas same error :

```
Could not find org.geotools:24.1
```

build.gradle :

```
geotools_version = '24.1'

dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junit_version}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junit_version}"

    implementation "org.geotools:${geotools_version}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependecies are defined by groupId, artifactId and version.
You only referenced groupId and version.